# Spring - How to bind form data to a List in model

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

I have a User model which has a list of address, on User form person can add as many as addresses he wants, how can I bind this data directly to address list?

one way I found is to do like below in jsp, but this requires index variable to add.

`<form:input path="address[0].street" type="text"/>
    <form:input path="address[0].state" type="text"/>
    <form:input path="address[0].postalcode" type="text"/>`

Is there any way to set this data dynamically

Answer (score 0):

you can use foreach like below code

```
<c:forEach items="${allAdresses}" var="address" varStatus="status">
    <form:input path="address[${status.index}].street" type="text"/>
    <form:input path="address[${status.index}].state" type="text"/>
    <form:input path="address[${status.index}].postalcode" type="text"/> 
</c:forEach>
```

and if you have new Address you just add new object in allAdresses Array

Comment: I need to add objects from jsp to model. What you are suggesting is for display data from model to jsp.

Comment: i thinks this linke contians what you want 
 http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-mvc-multi-row-submit-java-list/
and i have edit the post with sample

Comment: Thanks, the solution in the link shared is perfect for known list size, but for dynamic addition or removal, it wont work.

Answer (score 0):

One workaround you can try,  create an `AddressWrapp`er object which accepts list of address . And use this `AddressWrapper` object inside `user` model

```
class AddressWrapper{

private List<Address> addressWrapper;
    //generate getters and setters
}
```

Use this wrapper object for binding address.

```
class User{

private AddressWrapper addressWrapper;
//generate getters and setters

}
```

Comment: can you also share the way to bind values in AddressWrapper from jsp.